# Objective-C protocol property compiler warning

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I can't get rid of compiler warning when I define property inside protocol. Strange thing is that I have two properties defined, and I only get warnings for the second one (which is object type, while the first property is value type).

Here is screenshot:

[image: compiler warning]

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this warning, and why it is generated? The code is working normally, it is just this warning that annoys me :)

Comment: You haven't used `@synthesize` to create the getters/setters.  (And your code would fail if you attempted to access property `view`.)  The UI works because it can't find `view` and it tolerates that.

Comment: What happens if you rename `view` to something like `theView`?

Comment: I gave it name "view" on purpose. I explained it in other reply bellow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the compiler cannot find an implementation for the properties you defined in the protocol.

For this reason, it is not recommended to add properties to a protocol, instead, you would define just a simple method to access the property, and one to set it. That would give you the proper error messages, and while you couldn't use dot-notation, it keeps the warnings in the right place.

Alternatively, you could do something like this (not recommended, but for educational reasons):

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@protocol myProto

@property (assign) int myProperty;

@end

@implementation NSObject(myProto)

-(int) myProperty
{
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, "myProperty") intValue];
}

-(void) setMyProperty:(int) myProperty
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, "myProperty", [NSNumber numberWithInt:myProperty], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}

@end

@interface MyObj : NSObject<myProto> 

@end

@implementation MyObj

@dynamic myProperty;

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        MyObj *myObj = [MyObj new];

        myObj.myProperty = 10;

        NSLog(@"%i", myObj.myProperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JackyBoy what did I tell you about stalking?

Comment: I already told you, lol. I am not stalking no one. Besides, it's just to damn easy for you to actually know who I am, than the other way around. Btw, send me an email, when you actually start the blog.

Comment: declaring a property is exactly the same as declaring a pair of getter/setter methods. There is no reason not to declare properties in protocols

Comment: @newacct there actually is. Xcode puts the warnings in the wrong places, making them appear in the protocol definition instead of the implementing class.

Comment: I wonder why compiler can't find implementation of properties if property already exist in implementing class? UIViewController subclass that implements my protocol already have "view" property synthesized, right?

Comment: No. You cannot have a synthesized property in a protocol, period. You must use the work around I provided.

Comment: Ok, for now I will assume this is the accepted answer. But I will give a bit more time for others to give their own opinions. After that, if nothing changes, I will mark your answer as the correct one :) I will change my protocol to have methods instead of property, although I find it as a compiler limitation :)

Comment: "You cannot have a synthesized property in a protocol" This statement doesn't even make sense. "synthesize" or not is an implementation detail of how you implement a property. Implementing the getters and setters yourself has the same effect as synthesize. It does not have anything to do with the declaration of the property, even in normal classes. Since we are talking about declaration of property in protocol (protocol is only declarations), "synthesize" is irrelevant.

Comment: "'synthesize' is irrelevant" That's not quite true, although it used to be.  @synthesize now also creates an instance variable for the property.

Answer (score 2):

In your program, the property is called `view`. There must be a getter called `view` and a setter called `setView`. If you do not use `@synthesize` you must supply these two methods, and this is the reason of the compiler warning. 
The code is working normally because you do not reference the property using dot notation or call the getter and setter methods.

Comment: -1 for the first sentence here: `Property is a way to define an instance variable and then use dot notation to access it`. Wrong, so very very wrong.

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III, sorry, what is wrong?. I tried to be simple explaining the warnings

Comment: All that `@property` does is defines a getter / setter pair, which do not have to be linked to an iVar. For example: `MyClass.new` is perfectly valid use of dot-notation, albeit very strange. Dot-notation can be confusing, as it can be applied to any method that takes no parameters and returns a value.

Comment: The protocol I defined is meant to be used by other classes/controllers, not in the one I supplied code for. To be more precise, protocol will be implemented by other controllers most of the time, so I have chosen "view" property on purpose, since controllers already have that property synthesized (or am I wrong here?). In all controller classes that implement protocol, I synthesize only "pageIndex", and I assume other property already exist in UIViewController parent class. I do reference view property in implementig classes using dot notation, and all is working ok.