# Property or not property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

Quick question about semantics :)

If I was writing a protocol, which is preferred:

```
// (a)
@protocol MyProtocol 

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSSet *things; 

@end
```

vs.

```
// (b)
@protocol MyProtocol

- (NSSet *)things;
- (void)setThings:(NSSet *)things;

@end
```

(a) is cleaner code but has the implication that implementing classes will have an ivar for `things`, which isn't the case in my project. Because of my use case, `things` cannot be KVO either. It also implies that the implementing class will `copy` `things`, which it's not doing in every case for me.

(b) is more accurate code (it's very explicit about what you can / can't do i.e. no KVO) but it's a little messier.

Any opinions?

Comment: How is (b) "messier"?

Comment: the variant a has copy property. Isn't it simpler then doing it with getter and setter methods?

Comment: You've assumed that the implementation is going to copy things at all - some implementations might break it down and store / display it in a totally different way.

Comment: @rmaddy more lines of code. Harder to read lines as well - objective-c developers are very used to parsing lines that start `@property` :)

Comment: @deanWombourne You mean newer Objective-C developers. Properties have only been around a few years. Earlier versions of Objective-C didn't have properties. Before then, option (b) was the only option.

Comment: @deanWombourne As an Objective-C developer I would read option (b) easier since I would be scratching my head for some time trying to figure out what a property is doing inside a protocol! lol See my answer for more details on my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protocols define messaging contracts [[1]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW1). They are not intended to store data. According to the Apple documentation you are only supposed to add properties to class extensions (you can add properties to categories but the compiler won't synthesize an ivar) [[2]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW1). Depending on what you are trying to do I would use one of the two following approaches to be consistent with the documented usage of the Objective-C language:

> 1. If you have the source code of the class (its one you created) then use a class extension.
> 2. If you do not have the source code sub-class the object.

That being said, if you really need to do it the other way use option (b). It is more corect and more correct ***is*** cleaner code!

Here is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310121/objective-c-protocol-property-compiler-warning) that deals with the same issue.

Good luck

Answer (score 3):

I am amending my answer that (a) probably is not best for a protocol but best for a non-protocol interface.

I would go with the `@property`. How a property is implemented is an implementation detail and I never consider that from the outside.

Consider a v1 implementation where the property is only that. In v2 the internals are changed and either the setter or getter is made a method. Totally reasonable, one of the reasons that properties are good, they allow such changes, they hide the implementation details.

Also consider the opposite, in the next version where is is desired to remove the methods and replace them with a property. Again an implementation detail that a property in the first instance covers quite well.

Finally, in this case there is a `copy` attribute which provided explicit information of how a call with a mutable object will be handled, that is lost in the method implementation.

Comment: Plus you get to use dot syntax with properties.

Comment: @ansible Dot notations can be used with methods as well, it is just not good form and auto-completion does not work properly. Heck you can do `NSMutableString.alloc.init` -- but don't.

Comment: Isn't it the job of a protocol _not_ to define implementation details like `copy`? I have the copy as being a negative point to option (a)! In my app, some implementations of this _don't_ copy `things`.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the intent. If the protocol is a delegate it seems reasonable to know what might happen if I call with a mutable object. Here the `copy` it letting me know that my object will not be mutated as a side effect.

Comment: @Zaph - crazy.  How about you can use dot syntax with properties without getting yelled at on SO :P

Answer (score 0):

I think case 'a' makes misinformation: class adopting protocol MyProtocol can follow not rules nonatomic and copy.

And for me it's very odd add properties inside protocols. It is going against paradigms of object oriented programming: delegates shold do some action, not provide informations.

So I advice you not use 'a' and 'b' cases, but to think again about yours programm architecture.